# How can PreciseFlight speedbrakes double the drag while being so small?

Tags: flight-controls, drag, airspeed, spoilers

Look at this photo of some PreciseFlight© speed brakes:
[image: PreciseFlight Speedbrakes installed on a Cessna 180]

On the website it is claimed that these little red plates can double drag and descent rates. I cannot believe that. Can this be true, and if yes, can you explain please how these small things can double the drag ?

Comment: What about [these speedbrakes, essentially big holes](https://d29y7fsthxbb26.cloudfront.net/catalog/graphics/05-07201.jpg)? Same manufacturer, same doubling of drag/descent rate.

Comment: @mins surely this isn't serious ?

Comment: @Programmer It is serious. And don’t call him/her Shirley.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Essentially](https://www.aviationconsumer.com/uncategorized/speedbrake-mods-questionable-for-some/), they are selling a *spoiler*.

The way they can claim "doubling the drag" may be as follows:

The device spoils lift, thereby *reducing lift cofficient*.  This results in the aircraft either having to fly faster to make the same lift, or at a higher AoA.  Analysis of airfoil drag polars do show a sharp reduction of Lift/Drag ratio as AoA increases.  Increasing speed will also increase drag exponentially.

The spoiler is not to be confused with *flaps*, which *increase lift coefficient*, allowing the aircraft to fly *slower* while maintaining lift (higher flap settings are generally used strictly to increase drag), making them useful for landing approaches.

While spoilers are valuable on extremely low rate of descent aircraft such as gliders, benefits of *higher approach speeds* are dubious for powered recreational aircraft.  Some pilots may favor them over the old fashioned, but highly effective, forward slip.

Comment: Oh yes, the reduction in lift seems plausible, thank you ! +1

Comment: Also note that the Mooney's equivalent flat plate area is only 400 sq in, so the speed brakes are easily most of the way there on projected surface area alone.

Comment: One can see how jet pilots might like them, adding drag rather than changing throttle.  Need to know their effect on the *stall speed* of the aircraft.

Comment: "*The device spoils lift*", if it spoiled lift it would be spoiler, not a [speedbrake](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2016/october/flight-training-magazine/how-it-works-speed-brakes). If they stalled the wing on this small width, it would be a limited effect. I rather think the holes create large eddies, an efficient source of drag.

Comment: @mins this device came out more than 20 years ago.  Some pilots liked it because it helped stick fast landings.  My preference is a tail speedbrake, like the F-86 Sabre has.

Comment: You are on the right track but missing a key ingredient: The local loss of lift spoils the lift **distribution** over span, increasing **induced** drag substantially. I predict that the strongest effect of these spoilers is at low speed when induced drag is dominant, but did not look for proof.